# I have 4 facets set to filter results by taxonomy terms but only one of the four filters work

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I'm using Apache SOLR with Facet API and am having trouble getting my facets to show. I have 4 facets that are set to filter results by taxonomy terms. Each filter uses a different vocabulary. For some reason only one of the four filters work. The other three don't even show up. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I went to the facet settings and under the "Empty facet behavior" section I selected "display text". This shows the title of the other facets, but there aren't any filter choices/options under the title to choose from.

Comment: Do you have any records that have those fields? Try setting Minimum facet count to zero. That should show the facet regardless of whether there are any results or not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the corresponding blocks for each facet are set in sidebar region (or where ever you want them to be?).